Showing custom video stream in IMG element
I am working on a Blazor WASM app that needs to show a Axis camera video stream. As I don't want to expose the credentials, I want to serve the stream using a custom API.
The camera stream (for my examples):
http://192.168.0.195/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi

Camera configured for anonymous viewing (for testing)
Opening this locally in my Chrome browser: shows the stream
Opening this in VLC: shows the stream

The API controller code:
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStream()
{
    var cameraUrl = "http://192.168.0.195/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi";

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(cameraUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, "Failed to retrieve stream from camera.");
    }

    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "multipart/x-mixed-replace");
}

When running the API controller:

Opening the endpoint (https://localhost:7283/v1/camera/stream) in Chrome: Black screen
Opening the endpoint in VLC: WORKS!

When adding it to my Blazor app:
<img src="https://localhost:7283/v1/camera/stream" alt="Live Camera Feed" />

Is shows a broken image icon.
Question
What am I missing here? The stream does work in VLC, but the browser is not showing it while the original stream is..

Not sure if it matters, but Cors is enabled on the API server side:
services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicies.NmsCorsPolicy,
policy =>
{
policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7036")
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowCredentials();
});
});

In my original code, the boundary was not defined in the content type. This is necessery for the client to seperate parts of the stream (in my case I assume frames).
I used Postman to check the original stream and saw that "boundary=myboundary" was defined. Adding the same to my API controller fixed the problem:
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary");

Note that "myboundary" is just a custom string that happened to be used by the camera I am using. This could be different for other streams.
